# MySQL Replace Breaks Wordpress Template

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I am making a copy of a WordPress website on another server. Everything is OK in copying the database.

However, I need to replace the old domain name "old.com" with "new.com" in some MySQL tables. I am using the following query:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE(option_value, 'https://old.com/', 'http://new.com/')
```

This works for a lot of things (like the site URL), however, it breaks all my CSS modifications to the template and all my options, it's sort of restored into default settings directly after I run the previous command.

What could be the reasons?

Comment: manual search replace as data is serialised

Answer (score 3):

When moving a Wordpress table the Database Search and Replace Script by interconnect/it does the job very well.
https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/

The software is designed for exactly the purpose of replacing olddomain.com with newdomain.com.

All you do is extract Search Replace DB to it's own directory off the root of the Wordpress installation. You then run

newdomain.com/Search-Replace-DB-master

This will automatically find your Wordpress database and will provide search and replace field. It allows a dry run where you can check the results before doing the live run.

Hope this is useful. I have used this many times when changing the domain for a Wordpress installation and it works every time.

Answer (score 0):

Never manually replace URL use https://wordpress.org/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/ plugin to safely search & replace old URL with new one.

Comment: But I want it to be automated. I can't do this with the plugin.

Comment: Plugin will replace all the URL automatically. Can you share what’s the issue doing with plugin so that I can share the solution.

Comment: No, I mean I need to run this "process" each 10 or 20 minutes automatically. This plugin won't help.

Comment: Can you share the reason behind running this process each 20/30 min also may I know do you have shell access to your server ?